# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from domain.com/WebService.svc?xsd=xsd0

Tags: php, soap, php-7.1

#### Problem

I am working on a web service and I am unable to connect always get this error message:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from domain.com/WebService.svc?xsd=xsd0

I did went to all of the SO questions I did not find a solution.

#### Server

Linux, php7.1

#### PHP Modules Enabled

```
bz2, calendar, Core, ctype, curl, date, dom, exif, fileinfo, filter, ftp, gd,
gettext, hash, iconv, intl, json, ldap, libxml, mbstring, mysqli, mysqlnd,
openssl, pcntl, pcre, PDO, pdo_dblib, pdo_mysql, pdo_sqlite, Phar, posix,
readline, Reflection, session, shmop, SimpleXML, soap, sockets, SPL,
sqlite3, standard, sysvmsg, sysvsem, sysvshm, tokenizer, wddx, xml, 
xmlreader, xmlwriter, xsl, zip, zlib
```

#### Code

```
$wsdlFile = **fullpathtowsdlfile**;
$context = stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
                // set some SSL/TLS specific options
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            ],
             
            'http'=>array(
                'user_agent'=>'SoapClient'
            )
             
        ]);

$options = array(
            'trace'=>1,
            'location'=>self::$wsdl,
            'exception'=>1,
            'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            //'stream_context'=>$context, // disable but leaved for reference.
            'local_cert'=> **fullpath**,
            'soap_version'=> SOAP_1_1
        );

$client =  new \SoapClient($wsdlFile, $options);
```

Also tried the Url instead of the Wsdl file and I get the same error. I can connect to the url via telnet domain 80 , telnet domain 413 and with my browser.

What I am missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is a public WSDL or is protected by some kind of authentication system ( like IP address check for example )? Can you post the WSDL address?

Comment: is an intranet wsdl :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a self signed certificate, updated my code to this and now the error is gone.

```
$context = stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
                // set some SSL/TLS specific options
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            ] 
        ]);

$options = array(
            'trace'=>1,
            'exception'=>0,
            'stream_context'=>$context,  

        );
$client =  new \SoapClient($wsdlFile, $options);
```